# Cambiar tipo de dato TIME a DATE - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día, tengo una duda ,ocurre que por error cambie el tipo de dato, en mi caso tenía **DATETIME**, pero al momento de cambiar el dato en el design del SQL por motivos de consulta mas sencilla yo le coloque **TIME** en vez de DATE por error a la columna FECHA, por lo que las fechas se me borraron y a parte no me deja volver a colocar el tipo de dato **DATE**, me muestra el mensaje que adjunto a continuación los cuales me indican que no es posible compatible TIME con DATE, como se observa solo tengo el tipo de dato time y solo se visualizan los 00:00 del tiempo, antes de este error me salía la fecha y la horas en cero, como lo podría cambiar a date y en el mejor de los casos recuperar las fechas que estaban en el inicio, se puede? o tengo que importarla otra vez y relacionarla con las otras tablas, ya que originalmente es una tabla de Access . Gracias de antemano , saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No podrás hacerlo directamente, tendrías que pasar primero a datetime y luego a date, algo asi:

```
ALTER TABLE TU_TABLA ALTER COLUMN NOMBRE_CAMPO DATETIME;
GO
ALTER TABLE TU_TABLA ALTER COLUMN NOMBRE_CAMPO DATE;
```

Aunque realmente nunca he hecho algo parecido, lo mas seguro es que no puedas recuperar la fecha ya que al cambiar a time la fecha se truncó en el registro original.

Comment: Hice lo que comentaste, a veces lo obvio se nos pasa por alto, sin embargo ocurrió lo que me dijiste , la perdida de datos.

Comment: Lamentablemente al hacer el cambio a TIME se trunca la parte de la fecha, aun cuando regresas a DATETIME te lo refleja cómo 1900-01-01 HH:MM:SS, pero si aun tienes una tabla origen y un ID que te permita identificar el registro, podrias cargar la tabla de access nuevamente con otro nombre y luego hacer el update solo de las fechas.

Comment: Tengo la tabla original pero no se como hacer el update que me indicas a final, he estado investigando y no se si se pueda hacer una importación de solo la columna la cual se me borraron los datos a la columna de la tabla que tiene el error mediante un query , he estado intentado sin éxito, porque lo de cargar la tabla como me indicas con el registro no me queda muy claro ya que no llevo mucho en la práctica